# Call AJAX from a PHP script

Tags: php, ajax

I am aware that I can call PHP scripts after processing an AJAX request, but am I able to do it the other way around?

I am writing a dynamically sized navigation component for a new website and I want to refresh the nav every time a new item is added to the Menu.

In my menu class I am currently thinking of using this approach to achieve the effect:

```
public static function new_item($label, $link) {

    $pos = self::num_items();        

    $DB = Database::getInstance();

    $query = $DB->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO menu VALUES('', :label, :link, :pos )");
    $query->execute(array(':label'=>$label,
                          ':link' =>$link,
                          ':pos'  =>$pos+=1  
                   ));

    ?>

    <script>

        function refreshHeader() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:  "my url",
                success: function() {
                    // refresh the header here somehow
                }
            });
        }

    </script>

    <?php
}
```

However, every time this runs I see nothing in my console (even when I put a valid url into my function), will I be able to achieve what I want this way or would I be better processing appending the tab to the document via AJAX and then calling the insert method in my Menu class on the success callback?

The only reason I ask is I feel this way may look neater in comparison to the other way of handling it, although I may be completely wrong.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated - cheers
Alex.

Comment: why aren't you using CURL ?

Comment: cURL for what? That does not make any sense.

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan CURL? Sorry I've been away from web for some time, what benefits would that give me?

Comment: By "refresh the header" you mean reload the HTML part representing your header, right? If yes then you need to return the new HTML part in your initial `$.ajax` call and replace the old one with the new one in the `success` callback.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv thats exactly what I want to do, thankyou

Comment: Or, if you have all the information, maybe add it using jQuery or some other DOM manipulation technique.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv yes I thought about using the appendChild() method to handle this, but I think a complete refresh would not hurt - may do some testing to see which is faster

Comment: I don't know how interested you are in learning JavaScript but you might want to look into a client-side MVC library like Knockout or Angular after learning the jQuery way.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv actually I'm quite interested in learning it, always enjoyed learning the more complex way of doing things, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

echoing the following line can call out existing javascript functions and you are even able to insert variables (only strings and ints though).

```
echo "<style onload='jsfunction(\"$vars\")'></style>";
```

I find this one of the most simple ways to do this quickly.

Comment: its invisible and it works :P If I use it I like to throw it in a hidden div on the page, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I now understand what you want to do, what you need is websockets. When a piece of php code (sever side) is executed, you want something to happen in the browser (client side). Take a look at how live chats are made with javascript and websockets, long polling and other similar methods, that's what you need here.

This helped me a lot [What are Long-Polling, Websockets, Server-Sent Events (SSE) and Comet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)